# create a complex typehint return in python

Tags: python, python-typing

I am creating an abstract method where I would like to force a specific structure to be returned:

```
def get_items():
    raise NotImplementedError
```

It should be overwritten by this structure:

```
def get_items():
    ...
    return ({'one': ['first']}, {'two': ['first','second']})
```

so a tuple of two -> where each item is a dict -> and this dict has keys and the values should be a list -> with one or two items

I can of course do:

```
def get_items() -> tuple:
    raise NotImplementedError
```

but how can I force the rest of the structure?

Comment: [`-> Tuple[Dict[str, List[str]], Dict[str, List[str]]]`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html)?

Comment: okee, mhmh, but a list with exactly one or two items :-)

Answer (score 0):

Just to be clear, you can't "force" anything by type-hinting.

The type-hint that you want is:

```
def get_items() -> tuple[dict[str, list[str]], dict[str, list[str]]]:
    raise NotImplementedError
```

Also, you can't specify the length of the list with type-hint as lists are mutable objects (You can for tuples)

Comment: thanks, but this might be a better start. While reading other sources it looks to me like I would need to create my own type class, could that be a better solution?

Comment: Yes, having a dedicated, self-explanatory data structure is definitely a better approach

Answer (score 0):

If you need to be explicit about the length, use `tuple` instead of `list` (and return tuples, of course).

Then

```py
MyTuple = tuple[str] | tuple[str, str]
MyDict = dict[str, MyTuple]

def get_items() -> tuple[MyDict, MyDict]:
    return ({'one': ('first',)}, {'two': ('first','second')})
```

More descriptive names should be used for `MyTuple` and `MyDict`, but I don't know your use case.

Aliases here will help other programmers to a) read this annotation and b) reuse them in other code. For example, the following without aliases would be non-DRY and longer:

```py
...

# Without aliases type is dict[str, tuple[str] | tuple[str, str]]
def get_first_item() -> MyDict:
    a, _ = get_items()
    return a
```